# How to troubleshoot power issue on RPI2?

Tags: power, pi-2, boot-issues

I RPI2 is not booting up and just keeps both leds on in solid manner.

I've found a power troublesheeting guide for RPI1 http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Troubleshooting_power_problems
I'm wondering if there is a similar guide for RPI2? Are there points similar to TP1\TP2 where is can measure voltage? How can I diagnose fuse problems?

I tried two different SD cards and few PSUs. I own two of RPI2s and first one work fine with all the PSUs i tried and with both SD cards. While the second one stopped working (yes, it used to work for days before). I have no idea what changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you perform these tests in this order:

0) Check that your USB power adapter is working properly (5v, ~2A).  ( I assume it's OK since you mentioned that you have successfully powered other Pi units.  So I'm including this step for logical completeness.)

1) With power disconnected, check the polyfuse (near the USB input power jack) using a DMM ohm meter to determine if it is open or closed.  This resettable fuse is circuit protection for an overcurrent condition and normally resets itself after a few hours once tripped.

2) With power disconnected, check the TVS Diode (PCB location D5) using an external variable power supply at the USB power jack (constant @10ma, apply 5v and turn up to 8v) and use a DMM volt meter to observe shunt behavior.  This diode is circuit protection for an overvoltage condition and might be smoked and stuck in an open condition where it is shunting all your power to ground.

If you got this far, your 5v power rail appears good.

3) Now connect the power.  Check either of the GPIO 3v3 power pins using a DMM volt meter to determine if it's providing power at this level. If it is powered, that means your voltage regulator (buck converter) is working and it should also be supplying power to the SOC which performs the boot processing, so you may have a faulty SOC.  If the pin is not providing power, that suggests your regulator is faulty.

These few tests should narrow down the troubleshooting considerably.

Comment: Nice checklist! Thank you. Where exactly can i find the polyfuse? I used google with no luck

Comment: I don't have your model (Pi2) or I would post a photo.  My google search indicates the polyfuse on the Pi2 is on the underside of the board near the power jack, at location F1, and may be labelled "204E".  Note that if your LED light is on, this fuse is probably OK.

Comment: now i have a multimeter on hands and summarise this thread:

 1) works
 2) i don't have variable power supply, so i skipped this test
 3) +3.3v and +5v pins are powered correspondingly.

so now i can throw away that unit without fear :) thanks to all participants and especially to @PhilM

Answer (score 0):

This is a list of the test points on the Pis with the 40 pin expansion header.

```
PP1 5V from micro-USB
PP2 5V from micro-USB
PP3 GND
PP4 GND
PP5 GND
PP6 GND
PP7 5V after polyfuse
PP8 3V3
PP9 1V8
PP10 Goes from 3V3 to 2V on brownout
PP11 DAC_2V5 (for composite video DAC)
PP12 AUD_2V5 (for PWM audio drivers)
PP13 Goes from 3V3 to 2V on ACT activity
PP14 SD_CLK
PP15 SD_CMD
PP16 SD_DAT0
PP17 SD_DAT1
PP18 SD_DAT2
PP19 SD_DAT13
PP20 H5V
PP21 RUN signal (reset)
PP22 Goes from 3V3 to 2V on activity of green (link) ethernet jack LED
PP23 Goes from 3V3 to 2V on activity of yellow (speed) ethernet jack LED
PP24 COMPVID
PP25 AUDIO_L
PP26 AUDI_R
PP27 VBUS (USB 5V power)
PP28 ETH_CLK (25.000 MHz)
PP29 VC_TMS
PP30 VC_TRST_N
PP31 VC_CLK
PP32 VC_TDI
PP33 VC_TDO
PP34 GND
PP35 GPIO6 of LAN9514
PP36 GPIO7 of LAN9514
PP37 CAM_GPIO0
PP38 CAM_GPIO1
PP39 SCL0
PP40 SDA0
```

Source https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=628505#p628505

Comment: How come he needs this? Just curious.

Comment: "Are there points similar to TP1\TP2 where is can measure voltage? How can I diagnose fuse problems?"

Comment: Aha. Gotcha. Sorry bout that.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever my Pi2 doesn't have enough power, the Green LED kind of works and the Red one doesn't turn on, unless it's idling.

What I think you have here is a formatting issue on your SD card. Try downloading the N00Bs files from the website, then using unetbootin.github.io to install the iso. Always works for me, for RasPi and normal Linux. Other possibilities are:

1. You used the same .iso both times, and it's corrupted
2. You got your SD Cards off of eBay and they're fakes
3. You're simply unlucky
4. Your SD Card wasn't formatted in MS-DOS(FAT) (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=102231)

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok, finally received a new rapsberry pi 2 and now i can confirm that SD card is totally fine. new PI boots from that card, while the topic one cannot.